# How can I pass a value NSLabel from one representation to another. With storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, storyboard

How to pass values ​​from one controller to another? I use a StoryBoard.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier hasPrefix:@"FinishController"]) {
        FinishController *asker = (FinishController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        asker.FinishDesc = @"What do you want your label to say?";
        asker.FinishTitle = @"Label text";
        asker.FinishPoint = @"asdas";
    }
}
```

[image: storyboard]

I would like to appear on the highlighted text view of the first view.

Call the next view of the code, I think something like this should look like:
         UIStoryboard *finish = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

```
     UIViewController *viewController = [finish instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FinishController"];

     viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
     [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

finishcontroller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.lblFinishTitle.text=self.FinishTitle;
    self.lblFinishDesc.text = self.FinishDesc;
    self.lblFinishPoint.text=self.FinishPoint;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is using global variable possible? If so, take a look of something called "extern". Hope this gives you a direction =]

Comment: Say, in Example1.h, put down "extern UILabel *testLabel" in the header region. Then in Example1.m 's header region, put down "UILabel *testLabel". Then in Example2.m where you want to use the value, include Example1.h.

Comment: your decision is very bad = \